# TFS2010 Database Schema Explanation

Tags: sql-server, database-design, database-schema

By looking at the default, raw relational db schema of TFS2010 of its underlying team project collection sql database it is not necessarily self-explanatory how things work there and I was wondering whether someone has a more process oriented explanation how all these tables are related to each other. It seems like only 3 or 4 actually do have fk relations and such, the other ones are logically connected and would require joins and that's the part I am interested in & want to understand. Does anyknow have or know a more detailed explanation what's going on there?

Comment: Is there a scenario you are trying to query for or you are just generally curious?  I, along with many others, can help you build specific queries.  I am not aware of any site that details out all the db table relationships.  YOu could always model it out with a tool like EA

Comment: Not a specific scenario. We are currently starting to build up an entirely new team around a TFS based test management/planning/execution solution (+customizing) and we have a bunch of rather complex (from a business logic perspective) reports to generate and just by looking at the tables it's a bit confusing and often misleading a bit how to map our reports' requirements to the data available (or how to aggregate it properly). Hence the question whether some 'guidance' was available.

Comment: Don't use the Relational database. See [Creating, Customizing, and Managing Reports for Visual Studio ALM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb649552.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using the TFS cube for all reporting needs, microsoft does not recommend the use of relational database as this may impact performance. As a good start you can read up about the schema, enhancements, dimensions of the TFS 2010 cube on the msdn library http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff432837.aspx. Also this walkthrough is very helpful to get you started with reporting against the tfs cube http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730837.aspx#bkmk_tfsdb

HTH.

Cheers, Tarun